# Utilize a single button for several tasks

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am trying to have detection on, which tab is selected. In return to the selected tab, the "Add" button will open the corresponding window.

I have a separate function with the if statements to make sure the button click will open the corresponding window. However, it does not work like how I want it to work.

It does not matter what tab is selected it will open 2 tabs of the 3.

Here is the function code:

```
def tab_add_btn():
    if tab_parent.index(active_business):
        nieuwe_zaken.business()
    if tab_parent.index(noc):
        noc_info.add_noc_info()
    if tab_parent.index(caller):
        Form.add_caller()
```

The app is calling the other windows from different .py files within the project.

The add_noc_info and add_caller functions are opened every time I click on the button, no matter what tab is open. Even though I want to open the corresponding function to the opened tab.

I have tried several different statements/functions, without success.

```
# The function which is called by the button
def tab_add_btn():
    if tab_parent.index(active_business):
        nieuwe_zaken.business()
    if tab_parent.index(noc):
        noc_info.add_info()
    if tab_parent.index(caller):
        Form.add_caller()

# The button
add = ttk.Button(main_window, text = "Add", command = tab_add_btn)
add.place(x = 1093, y = 495)
```

I expect the button to open the corresponding windows (Functions) depending on which tab is opened/selected.

If you guys need more code snippets let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<notebook ref>.index(tabid)` is defined as ***"Returns the numeric index of the tab specified by tabid"***, therefore **all** your `if tab_parent.index(...` are always `True`. Do you mean `.select()`, which ***"returns the widget name of the currently selected pane. "***

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
def tab_add_btn():
    tabid = tab_parent.index(tab_parent.select())

    if tabid == 0:
        nieuwe_zaken.business()
        print("Window opened | Niewe Zaken")
    elif tabid == 1:
        noc_info.add_noc_info()
        print("Window opened | NOC Info")
    elif tabid == 2:
        Form.add_caller()
        print("Window opened | Bellers Form")
    else:
        return 0
```

I first had to get the tab_id before I could build the if statements.